# conditional left outer join SQL query To JPQL

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpql

[SQL FIDDLE LINK FOR THIS DATA](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3902/19/11)

What is a **jpql** equivalent of following **SQL** query :

```
select * from App left outer join App_Child on (App.id=App_Child.id and App_Child.status = 'active') where App.status='active' and App.id=1;
```

**Sample Data:**

```
ij> select * from App;
ID         |STATUS
----------------------
1          |active
2          |active1
3          |active3
5          |active

4 rows selected
ij> select * from App_Child;
ID         |STATUS    |D
----------------------------------
1          |active    |1
2          |active11  |2
1          |active111 |3
1          |active    |4

4 rows selected
ij> select * from App left outer join App_Child on (App.id=App_Child.id and App_Child.status = 'active') where App.status='active' and App.id=1;
ID         |STATUS    |ID         |STATUS    |D
---------------------------------------------------------
1          |active    |1          |active    |1
1          |active    |1          |active    |4

2 rows selected
ij> select * from App left outer join App_Child on (App.id=App_Child.id and App_Child.status = 'active') where App.status='active' and App.id=5;
ID         |STATUS    |ID         |STATUS    |D
---------------------------------------------------------
5          |active    |NULL       |NULL      |NULL

1 row selected
```

EDIT : We are using **jpa 2.0**

Comment: Can you do it with a sub-query instead of a join? JPQL allows sub queries and I have used this as a workaround myself in the past.

Comment: can you post your sub-query workaround ?

Comment: I posted the workaround. I'm interested to hear if it helped or not?

Answer (score 8):

The condition `App.id=App_Child.id` is automatically added because of the `@ManyToOne` relation. And in JPA 2.1, you can add additional conditions with an explicit `on` clause:

```
select a 
from App a left outer join 
     a.children c on (c.status = 'active') 
where a.status='active' and a.id=1;
```

See for example [EclipseLink Documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON).

Comment: is there anything equivalent to ON in jpa 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately none that I am aware of. Once we needed that functionality and we ended up resorting to a native query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a SQL query to find all App's that have an "active" App_Child you could try exists instead of join.

```
-- Alternative SQL to join
select a.* from App a where a.ID = 1 and exists (select * from App_Child b where a.id=b.id AND b.STATUS = 'active')
```

In your example you had two things going on. In the SQL example on this page you're just getting the columns from the App table. On your fiddle though you're getting columns from the App table as well as the App_Child with only the "active" child rows shown. This exists method will work for the first query where you just want to retrieve the App but if you want to fetch both the App and child together then it won't help.

What you could do though is add a method to the App entitiy to get a collection of Active App_Child and map an appropriate property. You can get the App's you want using this "exists" query and then call getActiveChildren on each App.

I tested the SQL on your fiddle, here is the edit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f39a/6/2

This reference shows you exists in JPQL.
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_exists

Hopefully that's enough info for you to try it out.